# ArrayDeleteAt - ColdFusion

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, cfml

I am using Array to store information for a request. At a point in the request, they can  add or delete information out of it.

The delete button passes the index to the page where the logic of the ArrayDeleteAt() is found.

In the page it has the following code:

```
<cfif (isDefined('form.deleteIndex'))>
<cfset temp = arrayDeleteAt(session.Request,form.deleteIndex)>
</cfif>
```

When deleting the first item, it does not delete the Struct out of the Array but clears the values for it. When deleting any of the other items it is fine, but I cannot get the empty struck out of the Array.

Create Array:

```
<CFSET VarArrayLen = ArrayLen(session.ord)>
<CFSET VARDuplicatedItem = "False">
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#VarArrayLen#">
    <CFIF session.ord[i].ITEMID eq ITEMID >
        <CFSET VARDuplicatedItem = "TRUE">
    </CFIF>
</CFLOOP>
<CFIF VARDUPLICATEItem eq "False">
    <cfset temp = arrayAppend(session.ord,StructNew())>
    <cfset session.ord[arraylen(session.ord)].ITEMID = ITEMID>
    <cfset session.ord[arraylen(session.ord)].ITEMDETAILS = ITEMDETAILS>
    <cfset session.ord[arraylen(session.ord)].FullRequestDetails = FullRequestDetails>
</CFIF>
```

One page where user is allowed to add or delete from array:

```
<CFSET VarArrayLen = ArrayLen(session.ord)>
<table>
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#VarArrayLen#">
        <CFIF ArrayIsDefined(session.ord,i) eq true>
            <tr>
                <cfform action="ActionPage.cfm" method="post">
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" value="#i#" name="del" />
                        <input type="image" src="/images/stop.gif" width="8" alt="delete this item" />
                    </td>
                </cfform>
            </tr>
        </CFIF>
    </CFLOOP>
</table>
```

On page where it deletes the item:

```
<cfif (isDefined('form.del'))>
    <cfset temp = arrayDeleteAt(session.ord,form.del)>
</cfif>
```

That is all the code.

In the Session it still shows the one item in the Array with all the values empty.

It is always the first item to be deleted that stays in the array and the rest are deleted fine.

Comment: interesting, but it'd be more useful if you can demonstrate the seemingly strange behavior in a test case.

Comment: Yeah, please post a [small, *self-contained*, repro case](http://www.sscce.org/) that we can test.

Comment: I have updated the coded on the page to show the follow script.

Comment: It's still not really self-contained. The repro should be a single file, called in a single request, which both populates the array and then demonstrates a working situation (a control), and a not working situation (the issue we're trying to help you with). Get rid of all the form submission, HTML, session scope, etc, and just demo *the problem*. This refactoring should be part of your own troubleshooting even before posting. It might help to read this: http://bit.ly/12ALYK0. Ignore the invective, it's an old article and not directed at you. It just helps explain how to troubleshoot better.

Comment: Also, which CF version are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to extract your problem into a self-contained test case, but I cannot reproduce your problem using CF10.

```
<cfset session.orders = [{item='blah',qty=1},{item='blah2',qty=2}]>

<cfdump var="#session.orders#" format="text"
        label="before arrayDeleteAt(session.orders, 1)">

<cfset arrayDeleteAt(session.orders,1)>

<cfdump var="#session.orders#" format="text"
        label="after arrayDeleteAt(session.orders, 1)">
```

Output:

```
before arrayDeleteAt(session.orders, 1) - array - Top 2 of 2 rows

1) [struct]
    ITEM: blah
    QTY: 1 
2) [struct]
    ITEM: blah2
    QTY: 2 
after arrayDeleteAt(session.orders, 1) - array - Top 1 of 1 rows

1) [struct]
    ITEM: blah2
    QTY: 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have solved the problem. My add and delete function was in the same CFM page, but I though I divided two with a CFIF statement but i didn't. When it deleted it ran the add and since the values was not there it inserted empty string into array.

Comment: That being the case, I suggest that you withdraw your question.

Comment: Definitely do that, yes.